# A question which belongs to a class of Zygmund functions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be an absolutely continuous, periodic with period 1  and satisfies the condition 
$$
|f(x+\delta)+f(x-\delta)-2f(x)|\leq \text{const}\frac{\delta}{(\log\frac{1}{\delta})^{\epsilon}}, \,\,\,\delta\in (0,1), \,\,\epsilon\in (0, 1].  
$$
My question is that for any $I=[a, b],$ which is $|I|<1$ the following inequality 
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}\Big|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}\Big|dx\leq \text{const}\frac{|I|}{(\log\frac{1}{|I|})^{\epsilon}}
\end{equation}
is true? If it is how can I show?

Comment: The Article "A Note on Smooth Functions" from Weiss and Zygmund contains also information about your class of functions. http://goo.gl/ha7i4l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Zygmund class (with $\epsilon=0$) is the Besov space
$
B^1_{\infty,\infty},
$
that is using a Littlewood-Paley decomposition
$$
1=\sum_{\nu\ge 0}\varphi_\nu(\xi),\quad \varphi_\nu(\xi) =\phi(\vert\xi\vert 2^{-\nu}) \text{ for $\nu\ge 1$, supp$\phi=[r,R], r>0,\ \varphi_0\in C^\infty_c$,}
$$
$$
f\in B^1_{\infty,\infty} \text{  means}\ \sup_\nu2^\nu\Vert \varphi_\nu(D)u\Vert_{L^\infty}<+\infty.
$$
I guess that your class of functions is characterized by
$
\sup_\nu\nu^\epsilon2^\nu\Vert \varphi_\nu(D)u\Vert_{L^\infty}<+\infty
$
and hope it can help for your problem by generalizing what is known for the true Zygmund class.

Comment: Thank you very much Dear Bazin. They are  very useful facts,   could you suggest me any literature regarding to these  facts.

Comment: The book Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations, Grundlehren Vol. 343 by Bahouri, Hajer, Chemin, Jean-Yves, Danchin, Raphaël contains plenty of information on basic Fourier analysis.